# blinitializelibrary failed 0xc00000bb

Tags: windows, windows-10

I am trying to reinstall Windows 10 on a GPT partition SSD from a GPT partition  FAT32 USB stick. When I'm trying to boot from the stick I get `blinitializelibrary failed 0xc00000bb`. What I found on google didn't help. This happened to me before about 2 years ago and I have managed to fix the problem, but I completely forgot how I did it.

I have tried with secure boot disabled but it didn't work.

I'm using an ASUS ROG Rampage VI Extreme motherboard.

Comment: What did you use to create the installation media?  This error has nothing to do with Secure Boot, so you can go ahead, and enable it.

Comment: i have used rufus

Comment: With Rufus make sure the options GPT/UEFI are selected before burning the ISO. Better yet since you're doing it in Windows is to use the official Media Creation tool. Actually there's no reason *not* to use, it's the default when downloading the ISO from Microsoft. I really don't understand why people go after third-party tools for such job.

Answer (score 0):

Rufus was not the problem. The problem was that I was making the bootable USB stick with GPT instead of MBR which fixed the problem.

Knowing that my SSD having the GPT partition scheme, I thought that the USB stick should have the same partition scheme to be able to boot the Windows installation.

I didn't want to make the USB stick with MBR partition scheme because I thought that it will change my SSD's partition scheme from GPT to MBR when doing a clean Windows install but it didn't change.